# Way to dump (copy) all DB objects from Oracle to Intellij

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea

Is there any way I can copy all my db objects (Functions, Triggers, Tables, Views, Procedures and Packages) from Oracle and check-in to IntelliJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As says, you can connect to your database, but I think you are looking for a way to checkin your object ddl definitions into SCM for sue in Intellij.

For what its worth, you can use [database export](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/export-intro-1-161239.html) with [Oracle SQLDeveloper](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sql-developer.html) and configure your SCM to commit the generated files to it.

Comment: Thanks  Barry, This is what i was looking for :)

Comment:      Good stuff, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Database objects are stored in a database, there is no need to copy them from SQL developer. To connect to the database from IDEA follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html